# Hiding text correction box in microsoft word when editing text

Tags: microsoft-word

Sorry for what I'm sure is an incredibly straighforward question, but I simply cannot find what this box is called and how to remove it.

[image]

When using Word, and selecting text, a popout box - giving me the option of editing text (changing font, highlighting etc) appears, and then disappears when I stop highlight a word or phrase. I have attached an image of this box to this post.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this box from coming up at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called the "mini toolbar". You can disable it from `Word Options` > `General` > toggle `Show Mini Toolbar on selection`

[image]

- With the setting enabled

[image]

- With the setting disabled

[image]

Comment: Solved, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Alex feel free to put a tick in the box, as well.